# Differentiation inverse function using Maple

Tags: calculus, maple

Let $f(x)=2x^2-2,\quad (x \ge 0)$.

Find $\left. \frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(x)\right|_{x=0}$

Note that $f(1)=0$.

Use $\left. \frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(x)=\right. \ 1/ f'[f^-{1}(x)]$

Got the answer manually. But how do I key it in Maple?

Comment: I would advise you to go visit maple primes.

Answer (score 2):

Examine these steps and see if you agree with them, in terms of what you've learned of the formula for the derivative of the inverse (eg. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation)).

The equation assigned to `R` is a substitution for $f^{(-1)}(0)=1$.

```
restart;
P := diff((f@@(-1))(y),y);
f := x -> 2*x^2-2;
D(f);
P;
eval(P, y=0);
f(1)='f'(1);
R := map(f@@(-1), f(1)='f'(1) );
eval(eval(P, y=0), R);
```